# Hibernate JOIN Dot node with no left-hand-side

Tags: hibernate

I have a SQL query which works this is:

```
 select x.*,s.* from ID_LOOKUP x JOIN SOURCE_DATA s ON x.IDENTIFIER = s.SOURCE_PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER;
```

this works as expected but when I try doing the same thing in hibernate I get an error saying

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side!
```

My hibernate code is as follows

```
 Query q = session.createQuery("select x,s from com.package.IdLookupHDO x JOIN com.package.SourceDataHDO s ON x.identifier = s.sourcePrimaryIdentifier");
```

I am relatively new to hibernate and cannot figure why this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query must work for you:

```
select x,s 
from com.package.IdLookupHDO x, com.package.SourceDataHDO s
where x.identifier = s.sourcePrimaryIdentifier
```

Anyway, it will be useful that you post the code of `IdLookupHDO` and `SourceDataHDO` classes. If that entities are related someway, the query can be surely optimized and improved.